# Drop column with low variance in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I'm trying to drop columns in my pandas dataframe with 0 variance.
I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I had a lot of trouble finding a thread on it. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799187/drop-columns-with-low-standard-deviation-in-pandas-dataframe), however when I tried the solution for my dataframe, `baseline` with the command

```
baseline_filtered=baseline.loc[:,baseline.std() > 0.0]
```

I got the error

```
    "Unalignable boolean Series provided as "

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

So, can someone tell me why I'm getting this error or provide an alternative solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some non numeric columns, so `std` remove this columns by default:

```
baseline = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

#no A, F columns
m = baseline.std() > 0.0
print (m)
B     True
C     True
D    False
E     True
dtype: bool
```

So possible solution for add or remove strings columns is use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
baseline_filtered=baseline.loc[:,m.reindex(baseline.columns, axis=1, fill_value=True) ]
print (baseline_filtered)
   A  B  C  E  F
0  a  4  7  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  a
2  c  4  9  6  a
3  d  5  4  9  b
4  e  5  2  2  b
5  f  4  3  4  b

baseline_filtered=baseline.loc[:,m.reindex(baseline.columns, axis=1, fill_value=False) ]
print (baseline_filtered)
   B  C  E
0  4  7  5
1  5  8  3
2  4  9  6
3  5  4  9
4  5  2  2
5  4  3  4
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) working with strings and numeric columns:

```
baseline_filtered=baseline.loc[:,baseline.nunique() > 1]
print (baseline_filtered)
   A  B  C  E  F
0  a  4  7  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  a
2  c  4  9  6  a
3  d  5  4  9  b
4  e  5  2  2  b
5  f  4  3  4  b
```