# Drop automatically similar column effectively

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the extreme simplification of my data

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
    yue       78      758      uyf
    tue       78      785      uyf
```

My Expected output

```
Column2  Column3
     78      758
     78      785
```

What I did currently is using `df.describe()` and after that look all parameter who has 0 in standard deviation and drop column manually like df[['Column2', 'Column3']] in this case, but currently I have nore than 200 columns

Regards

Comment: You want `df[['Column2', 'Column3']]`?

Comment: No, what I want is drop column if all of its entry similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop columns with low standard deviation in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799187/drop-columns-with-low-standard-deviation-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
#returns columns with a standard deviation not equal to zero

df[df.columns[df.std()!=0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this ?  Idea is to iterate over each column and check the number of unique values. If the unique value is only `1`, then add that particular column to use_cols list.

```
use_cols = [cols for cols in df.columns if df[cols].nunique() ==1]
df= df[use_cols]
```